# New to PartiQL - what is wrong with this SELECT statement?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, partiql

Using DynamoDB with PartiQL, I am trying to select records using a global index:

```
SELECT *
FROM "My-Table.My-Index"
WHERE Foo = 'bar'
AND Timestamp >= 638014354649346173
AND Timestamp <= 638014355249346173
ORDER BY Timestamp
```

I am getting an exception of:

One or more errors occurred. (Statement wasn't well formed, can't be processed: Unexpected keyword)

Not sure what I am doing wrong here as I am new to PartiQL syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM "My-Table"."My-Index"
WHERE "Foo" = 'bar'
AND "Timestamp" >= 638014354649346173
AND "Timestamp" <= 638014355249346173
ORDER BY "Timestamp"
```

Comment: This was correct. But didn't fully solve the problem. The attribute names also needed to be in double quotes. Perhaps this is a DynamoDB-specific limitation of PartiQL? Because I haven't seen that documented anywhere.

Comment: It depends on which platform/SDK you run the command but yes, typically the attribute names are in double quotes and attribute values in single quotes.